# What kind of hammer is this?

Tags: hand-tools

[image]

I can't find this specific hammer anywhere online,  does anyone know what it's called or used for?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a run-of-the-mill blacksmith's or stone sledge that someone has customized for a particular purpose.

Comment: i am gunna say upholstery  tack hammer.

Comment: If a black Smith hammer a big part of their job was horse shoes, that would support my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a tack hammer - also called an upholsterer's hammer.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like a farrier's hammer , long nose with a claw designed to twist off the nail. I have several but the hole at the base of the claw would need to be tapered.  I like the ones that twist to the side as they are easier to twist off the nails ( I only do emergency shoes can't have a lame horse on a long ride because it threw a shoe).

Answer (score 0):

Custom.  Closest is a mash hammer of stone buster but the cut isn't something I've seen.

Even google's coming up short for me so I'm going with custom mash hammer.